# OpenApi generated axios client keycloak support

Tags: reactjs, .net-core, keycloak, openapi

I am trying to build a React application with a .NET Core OpenAPI backend. I followed this tutorial to set up Keycloak for user identification: https://blog.devgenius.io/part-four-security-in-react-and-webapi-in-asp-net-b6dffd3b7624. However, I am having trouble using the KeyCloakService with the generated client from editor.swagger.io. Can someone please help me with this issue? Thank you.

The react testcode:

```
const openapiConfig = new Configuration();
openapiConfig.basePath = "https://localhost:44387";
openapiConfig.accessToken = getToken;

const WeatherTable: React.FC = () => {
    const openApi = new WeatherForecastApi(openapiConfig);
    const [items, setItems] = useState<Array<WeatherForecast>>([]);
    const fetchForecasts = async () => {
        openApi.getWeatherForecast().then((response) => {
            setItems(response.data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchForecasts();
    }, []);



    return (
        <Table>
            <tbody>
                {items && items.map((item, index) => (
                    <tr key={index}>
                        <td>{index}</td>
                        <td>{FormatDate(item.date)}</td>
                    </tr>
                ))}
            </tbody>
        </Table>
    );
};
```

The keycloakservice:

```
import Keycloak from "keycloak-js";

const keycloakInstance = new Keycloak();

/**
 * Initializes Keycloak instance and calls the provided callback function if successfully authenticated.
 *
 * @param onAuthenticatedCallback
 */
const Login = (onAuthenticatedCallback: Function) => {
    keycloakInstance
        .init({ onLoad: "login-required" })
        .then(function (authenticated) {
            authenticated ? onAuthenticatedCallback() : alert("non authenticated");
        })
        .catch((e) => {
            console.dir(e);
            console.log(`keycloak init exception: ${e}`);
        });
};

const UserName = () => keycloakInstance.idTokenParsed?.preferred_username;
const UserRoles = () => {
    if (keycloakInstance.resourceAccess === undefined) return undefined;
    else return keycloakInstance.resourceAccess["MyApp"].roles;
};

const Logout = () => keycloakInstance.logout;
const isLoggedIn = () => !!keycloakInstance.token;
const getToken = () => keycloakInstance.token;
const doLogin = keycloakInstance.login;
const updateToken = (successCallback: any) =>
    keycloakInstance.updateToken(5).then(successCallback).catch(doLogin);

const KeyCloakService = {
    CallLogin: Login,
    GetUserName: UserName,
    GetUserRoles: UserRoles,
    CallLogout: Logout,
    IsLoggedIn: isLoggedIn,
    GetToken: getToken,
    UpdateToken: updateToken,
};

export default KeyCloakService;
```

Answer (score 0):

This was simpler that I expected. Just initialize the api with the axios client.

```
const openApi = new WeatherForecastApi(openapiConfig, "https://localhost:44387", HttpService.getAxiosClient());
    const [items, setItems] = useState<Array<WeatherForecast>>([]);
    const fetchForecasts = async () => {
        openApi.getWeatherForecast().then((response) => {
            setItems(response.data);
        })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    };
```